# excel function or macro delete numbering in front of text

Tags: vba, excel

I searched but couldn't find any answer.Need your help tol solve the issues. so here is the problem:

I have a spreadsheet with

```
Cell A4 :  1.1 ABC             
Cell A5:   1.10 BCD 200 ABC              
Cell A6:   5.8 ABCD ABCD
```

So what I want is to delete 1.1 , 1.10 5.8 in front of the text including the space after the number as well.

I tried right function but didn't solved the issue.

```
Transformed Cell A4:ABC             
Transformed Cell A5:BCD 200 ABC               
Transformed Cell A6:ABCD ABCD
```

It should check all the A colomn till A100 for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work if you formulate it this way:

```
=RIGHT(TRIM(A1),LEN(TRIM(A1))-FIND(" ",TRIM(A1)))
```

By trimming, you're making sure you get rid of trailing spaces before dealing with the real problem (taking only what's to the right of the first remaining space)

---

Sometimes even if your language is set to English, your localization may be different from other users'. Changing all `,` into `;` may often time solve the "*We found a problem with this formula*" error message. In this case, this formula is compatible with @ahmet 's setup.

```
=RIGHT(TRIM(A1);LEN(TRIM(A1))-FIND(" ";TRIM(A1)))
```

---

Try this if you want to display *Error* when there's an error with the formula. Replace `"Error"` with `""` if you want the cell to remain empty if there is an error.

```
=IFERROR(RIGHT(TRIM(A1);LEN(TRIM(A1))-FIND(" ";TRIM(A1))); "Error")
```

Comment: Excel 2013 comes with an error. something like to get around this problem,type apostrophe(') first: you type "=1+1,cell shows =1+1 ... so it does not worked on my excel 2013

Comment: I'm in Excel 2013 as well. What language are you set to? Maybe you have to use the locale functions. For example, when I go on my "French" computer, I have to enter `=DROITE(A1; 1)` to do the equivalent as `=RIGHT(A1, 1)`

Comment: It's english :) ,  i am using RIGHT function but it does not accept the formula in total.

Comment: second one is working ohh I get it now :) I will replace above , with ; let me check

Comment: yes this formula is working now, strange problem :)    =RIGHT(TRIM(A4);LEN(TRIM(A4))-FIND(" ";TRIM(A4)))

Comment: Glad I could help you figure it out :D

Comment: Bernard, how can i improve the code for adding if error is error.I don't wan't to see #Value when the cell is empty ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=RIGHT(A1, LEN(A1) - FIND(" ",A1,1))
```

Comment: I tried this formula before asking but did not worked out.Excel 2013 comes with an error.  something like to get around this problem,type apostrophe(') first: you type "=1+1,cell shows =1+1 ... so it does not worked on my excel 2013.